# Custom resampling methods in R

Tags: r, timestamp, resampling

Dear users I was taking a look to the ways of resampling my time series data. Basically my problem is that I have to make a calculation with different signals that have different timestamps. At the beginning I thought in use the aproxfun() or the zoo package.

The problem is that I need to mantain the NAN values of t-1 and t+1 in case that they are present and only if certain conditions are fullfilled. In order to extract the different timestamps of the signals I did the following one:

```
GlobalTime<-sort(do.call(`c`, data[c(1, 3, 5)])) #extract the total timestamp of the measurements
Time1<-seq.POSIXt(from=min(data$X1, na.rm=TRUE), to=max(data$X1, na.rm=TRUE), by="s") #extract the timestamp of each measurment
Time2<-seq.POSIXt(from=min(data$X3, na.rm=TRUE), to=max(data$X3, na.rm=TRUE), by="s")
Time3<-seq.POSIXt(from=min(data$X5, na.rm=TRUE), to=max(data$X5, na.rm=TRUE), by="s")
#All vectors have different size
```

For the interpolation I need to consider 3 points. First one, from Time1 and 2 additional from Global Time (being these two the closest ones to Time1[i]). I thought that this can be done as:

```
upperlimits1=c()
lowerlimits1=c()
for (i in 1:length(actualTime)) {
    upperlimits1[i]=min(Mod(actualTime[i+1]-requestTime1[i]))
    lowerlimits1[i]=min(Mod(actualTime[i-1]-requestTime1[i]))     
}
```

Later in order to make the interpolation do something like that:

```
for (i in 1:length(actualTime)) {

if(lowerlimits1[i]==Time1[i])
resample[i,1]<-value[Time[i-1]]
resample[i,2]<-Time1[i-1]
resample[i,3]<-"OK"
i++    
} else if(upperlimits1[i]==Time1[i]){
resample[i,1]<-value[Time[i+1]]
resample[i,2]<-Time1[i+1]
resample[i,3]<-"OK"
i++    
} else if (upperlimits1[i]!=Time1[i] & lowerlimits1[i]!=Time1[i] & aux[i-1]=="Wrong"){
resample[i,1]<-value[Time1[i-1]]
resample[i,2]<-Time1[i-1]
resample[i,3]<-"Wrong"
i++
} else if (upperlimits1[i]!=Time1[i] & lowerlimits1[i]!=Time1[i] & aux[i+1]=="Wrong"){
resample[i,1]<-value[Time1[i+1]]
resample[i,2]<-Time1[i+1]
resample[i,3]<-"Wrong"
i++
} else if (aux[i]=="C"){
resample<-value[Time1[i-1]]
resample[i,2]<-Time1[i-1]
resample[i,3]<-aux[i-1]
i++
} else {
Delta=upperlimits1[i]-lowerlimits1[i]
if (Delta>3600){
resample[i,3]<-"Wrong"
} if (Delta<3600){
resample[i,3]<-"OK"
coeff=(Time1[i]-lowerlimits1[i]) / (upperlimits1[i]-lowerlimits1[i]);
resample[i,1]=value[lowerlimits1[i]] + (value[upperlimits1[i] - value[lowerlimits1[i]]) * coeff);
i++
}
```

Edit: as it was requested I add how my data  looks like:

```
Time1    Value1   Quality1   Time2      Value2    Quality2...
00:00.9  41.3       Ok       00:04.0    78.2         Ok                               
00:01.9  41.68      Ok       00:07.0    78.5         Ok                                
00:04.9  35.34      Ok       00:08.0    66           Ok                                 
00:15.9  35.98      Ok       00:14.0    65.8         Ok                                 
00:21.9  Wrong      Wrong    00:15.0    64.5         Ok                                   
00:22.9  38.9       Ok       00:19.0    40.5         Ok                                  
59:56.5  40.1       Ok       00:21.0    30.5         Ok
#of course sometimes wrong values can be recorded for longer periods as hours or days
#at the end the interpolation has the purpose of having the three or more signals with same timestamp
```

The desired output

```
Time1         Value1       Quality1   Time2      Value2    Quality2...
    01:00:00  IntValue       Ok       01:00:00   IntValue      Ok                               
    02:00:00  IntValue       Ok       02:00:00   IntValue      Ok                                
    03:00:00  IntValue       Ok       03:00:00   IntValue      Ok                                 
    04:00:00  IntValue       Ok       04:00:00   IntValue      Ok                                 
    05:00:00  IntValue       Ok       05:00:00   IntValue      Ok                                   
    06:00:00  IntValue       Ok       06:00:00   IntValue      Ok                                  
    07:00:00  IntValue       Ok       07:00:00   IntValue      Ok
```

But if quality column has been wrong for more than 24 hours the interpolation should write

However as you can imagine the code does not work. Have someone tried this before?

BR

Comment: Can you give a small example of your data and what the desired output would be when an NaN is present? Would it make sense to do a normal interpolation and then add the NaN's back into the data around a desired window of occurrence?

Comment: Added, what do you mean exactly with adding the NaN´s back?

Comment: Thanks for adding your data. Have you looked at the `na.approx` function in the `zoo` package? You can use it to resample your time series, and set a `maxgap` argument to not interpolate over longer than 24 hours.